# Aggregate contents of array column in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I have some data stored in the customEvents property bag that I want to perform aggregation and analytics on. I'm new to the analytics queries that you can run against AppInsights using the Azure Data Explorer query language and am stuck.

I have a handle on converting the contents of one of the property bag's key-value-pairs into an array of numbers (in the example below, that output is represented by `items`.

```
let items = parse_json('{"operation_Id": "12345Z12", "days":[43, 21, 65]}');
print items.operation_Id, items.days;
```

However, when I need to calculate the average value of the items in the array for each operation_Id, I run into a documentation wall. I've looked at `mvexpand`, `let` (using a lambda expression), `datatable`, using dynamic data types, etc. The blocking issue I've had with using `mvexpand` is that I want to associate every row in the output correlated with its operation `operation_Id`, and `mvexpand` only seems to persist that relationship in the first row. With a `datatable`, the type doesn't support a pipeline input.

Another common error I've (including from the code sample below is **Operator Source Expression should be table or column**).

```
let items = parse_json('{"days":[43, 21, 65]}');

let arraySum = (T:(x: long))
{
   T 
   | summarize sum(x) 
};
items
| project days | invoke arraySum()
```

If necessary, I can perform the aggregation code in JavaScript and only pass the calculated average in the property bag, but it feels like a waste to throw away the raw data values. Is there some obvious calculation or aggregation function that solves this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the following options should allow you to calculate the average as you're interested in:

(*caveat: this is based on the example you've shown, which may potentially be "dumbed down" to not reflect your real-life scenario, so please clarify in case this isn't helpful*):

```
let items = dynamic({"operation_Id": "12345Z12", "days":[43, 21, 65]});
print operationId = tostring(items.operation_Id), days = items.days
| mvexpand days to typeof(int)
| summarize avg(days) by operationId

// or

let items = dynamic({"operation_Id": "12345Z12", "days":[43, 21, 65]});
print operationId = tostring(items.operation_Id), days = items.days
| project operationId, series_stats_dynamic(days)['avg']
```

Your second example is indeed invalid (scalars and tabular arguments are not born equal), but could be rewritten as follows:

(*same caveat as above*)

```
let items = dynamic({"days":[43, 21, 65]});
let arraySum = (T:(x: long))
{
   T 
   | summarize sum(x) 
};
print items 
| mvexpand x = items.days to typeof(long)
| invoke arraySum()

// or

let items = dynamic({"days":[43, 21, 65]});
print items
| project sum = series_stats_dynamic(items.days)["avg"] * array_length(items.days)
```

---

***Updated examples following up the comments provided later on:***

```
datatable (Operation_id:string, customDimensions:dynamic) 
[ 
    "MTFfq", dynamic({"siteId": "1", "fileCount": "3", "pendingDays":[15,10,11]}), 
    "LXVjk", dynamic({"siteId": "2", "fileCount": "1", "pendingDays":[3]}),
    "jnySt", dynamic({"siteId": "3", "fileCount": "2", "pendingDays":[7,11]}), 
    "NoxoX", dynamic({"siteId": "4", "fileCount": "4", "pendingDays":[1,4,3,11]})
]
| mvexpand days = customDimensions.pendingDays to typeof(int)
| summarize avg(days) by Operation_id

// or

datatable (Operation_id:string, customDimensions:dynamic) 
[ 
    "MTFfq", dynamic({"siteId": "1", "fileCount": "3", "pendingDays":[15,10,11]}), 
    "LXVjk", dynamic({"siteId": "2", "fileCount": "1", "pendingDays":[3]}),
    "jnySt", dynamic({"siteId": "3", "fileCount": "2", "pendingDays":[7,11]}), 
    "NoxoX", dynamic({"siteId": "4", "fileCount": "4", "pendingDays":[1,4,3,11]})
]
| project Operation_id, series_stats_dynamic(customDimensions.pendingDays)['avg']
```

and:

```
let arraySum = (T:(x: long))
{
   T 
   | summarize sum(x) 
};
datatable (Operation_id:string, customDimensions:dynamic) 
[ 
    "MTFfq", dynamic({"siteId": "1", "fileCount": "3", "pendingDays":[15,10,11]}), 
    "LXVjk", dynamic({"siteId": "2", "fileCount": "1", "pendingDays":[3]}),
    "jnySt", dynamic({"siteId": "3", "fileCount": "2", "pendingDays":[7,11]}), 
    "NoxoX", dynamic({"siteId": "4", "fileCount": "4", "pendingDays":[1,4,3,11]})
]
| mvexpand x = customDimensions.pendingDays to typeof(long)
| invoke arraySum()

// or

datatable (Operation_id:string, customDimensions:dynamic) 
[ 
    "MTFfq", dynamic({"siteId": "1", "fileCount": "3", "pendingDays":[15,10,11]}), 
    "LXVjk", dynamic({"siteId": "2", "fileCount": "1", "pendingDays":[3]}),
    "jnySt", dynamic({"siteId": "3", "fileCount": "2", "pendingDays":[7,11]}), 
    "NoxoX", dynamic({"siteId": "4", "fileCount": "4", "pendingDays":[1,4,3,11]})
]
| project Operation_id, sum = series_stats_dynamic(customDimensions.pendingDays)["avg"] * array_length(customDimensions.pendingDays)
```

Some references for operators/functions used above:

- [series_stats_dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/series-stats-dynamicfunction)
- [array_length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arraylengthfunction)
- [mvexpand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator)

Comment: Your caveat is well taken since I'm running into issues integrating your suggestionsthe the `customDimensions` property that stores my data (according to the `getschema` operator, the reported data type is `dynamic`, so it's not clear what my integration issue is:

For example, when I run this query I get an error **Ensure that expression: items.siteName is indeed a simple name**

    let foo = customEvents | where name == 'Lock files selection submitted:' | 
    project customDimensions;

    print bar = tostring(foo.siteName);

Comment: as far as I'm able to read that last query, `foo` is actually a table with a single column (and `N` rows). so what you're trying to do is indeed invalid. If I try to derive the intention out of the query, consider trying the following: `customEvents | where name == 'Lock files selection submitted:' | project bar = tostring(customDimensions.siteName)`. allow me to also suggest: use the `datatable` operator to provide a synthetic data set that represents your data set, and then we can work with it (instead of trying to work with limited examples which don't reflect the real use case).

Comment: I hadn't thought of using a data table to create a synthetic, sample set of data. This should be a more representative of the data structure I have:

    ```datatable (Operation_id:string, customDimensions:dynamic)
    [
        "MTFfq", dynamic({"siteId": "1", "fileCount": "3", "pendingDays":[15,10,11]}),
        "LXVjk", dynamic({"siteId": "2", "fileCount": "1", "pendingDays":[3]}),
        "jnySt", dynamic({"siteId": "3", "fileCount": "2", "pendingDays":[7,11]}),
        "NoxoX", dynamic({"siteId": "4", "fileCount": "4", "pendingDays":[1,4,3,11]})
    ]```

Comment: thank you. I've added the examples based on this data set in the original reply, hopefully that'll answer the original question in a more relevant manner